# Where is a good starting place to do research on the algebra of quaternion numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, quaternions

I'm doing a project for my intro to real analysis class and decided that the algebra of quaternion numbers would be interesting to do. I'm wondering what a good starting place would be.

Comment: The quaternions really are more about abstract algebra than analysis, so that's kind of a weird choice for an analysis topic. it might make sense to report on what Banach algebras are, and use the quaternions as an example to study.

Comment: This is a good introduction at beginner level.. but it's in italian.
http://www.lilu2.ch/Jo3-dir/images/lam/statti.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than [Conway](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811349)